# how to set Calendar from JSpinner result value?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner, jcalendar

I am trying to make Calendar month&year picker.

How can I set calendar from two jspinner?

jspinner 1 = month value

jspinner 2 = year value

maybe it just to get int value from jspinner.. 
how to do it?

Here's my code:
(update)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
    import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;
    import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;


    public class datepicker extends JFrame{
       JSpinner Smonth = new JSpinner();
       JSpinner Syear = new JSpinner();
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       Date date = cal.getTime();
       SimpleDateFormat sdf_Month = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
       SimpleDateFormat sdf_Year = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
       SimpleDateFormat sdf_final_Date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy");
       JLabel label = new JLabel();

       datepicker(){
          Smonth.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, cal.MONTH));
          Smonth.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(Smonth, "MMMM"));
          Syear.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, cal.YEAR));
          Syear.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(Syear, "yyyy"));

          Smonth.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                   execute(); 

                }
            });

          Syear.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    execute();

                }
            });

          setLayout(new BorderLayout());
          add(Smonth, BorderLayout.WEST);
          add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
          add(Syear, BorderLayout.EAST);

          execute();
       }

           void execute(){


              cal.set(Integer.parseInt(sdf_Year.format(Syear.getValue())),
                  (Integer.parseInt(sdf_Month.format(Smonth.getValue())))-1,
                  1); 

              label.setText(sdf_final_Date.format(cal.getTime()));
           }

           public static void main(String[]args){
               new datepicker().setVisible(true);
           }    
    }
```

my complete simple date picker

```
 package Feature.Other;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Calender extends JDialog{
    private Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    public  java.sql.Date initDate = new  java.sql.Date(cal.getTime().getTime());
    private  JPanel north = new JPanel();
    private JPanel center = new JPanel();
    private JLabel lFinalDate=new JLabel("tanggal");
    private JLabel lDate[]= new JLabel[49];
    private String day[]= {"SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT"};
    private JSpinner smonth = new JSpinner();
    private JSpinner    sYear = new JSpinner();
    private DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
    private DateFormat sdfM = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
    private DateFormat sdfY = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");

    public Calender() {

        smonth.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(initDate, null, null, cal.MONTH));
        smonth.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(smonth, "MMMM"));
        JFormattedTextField jft = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)smonth.getEditor()).getTextField();
        jft.setEditable(false);
        jft.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        sYear.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(initDate, null, null, cal.YEAR));
        sYear.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(sYear, "yyyy"));
        JFormattedTextField jft2 = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)sYear.getEditor()).getTextField();
        jft2.setEditable(false);

        smonth.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                dor(); 
            }
        });

        sYear.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                dor();   
            }
        });

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(500,300);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){

        add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        north.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        center.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,7));

        addComponen(sYear, 2,0,1,1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
        addComponen(smonth, 0,0,1,1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
        addComponen(lFinalDate,1,0,1,1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);

        for (int i=0;  i<49;  i++ ){
          lDate[i]= new JLabel("");
          center.add(lDate[i]);

          if(i<7){
              lDate[i].setText(day[i]);
                }
        }
        dor();
    }

    private void addComponen(Component component,int gridx, int gridy, int gridwid, int gridheig,int achor, int fill){

        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy, gridwid, gridheig, 1.0, 1.0, achor,fill,new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0);
        north.add(component, gc);
    }

    private void dor(){
        cal.set(Integer.parseInt(sdfY.format(sYear.getValue())),
                Integer.parseInt(sdfM.format(smonth.getValue()))-1,
                1);
        lFinalDate.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lFinalDate.setText(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
        int dayMax = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int start = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        for (int i=7;  i<49;  i++ ){
          lDate[i].setText("");
          lDate[i].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }

        for (int a=6+start,b=1;b<=dayMax;a++,b++ ){
            final int selection = a;
            lDate[a].setText(""+b);
            lDate[a].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt){
                    cal.set(Integer.parseInt(sdfY.format(sYear.getValue())),
                        Integer.parseInt(sdfM.format(smonth.getValue()))-1,
                        Integer.parseInt(lDate[selection].getText()));
                    initDate = new  java.sql.Date(cal.getTime().getTime());
                    for (int z=6;z<=42;z++){
                    lDate[z].setForeground(Color.BLACK);}
                    lDate[selection].setForeground(Color.blue);
                    lFinalDate.setText(sdf.format(initDate));    
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[]args){
        new Calender().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- please read tutorial about [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)
- there is detailed desribtions about `JSpinner`, `SpinnerDateModel`, inc. code example about tutorial

EDIT

- there no reason to parse whatever, use proper SpinnerXxxModel,
- you can to test, to split to the three JSpinners as is described in the tutorial, simple code for SpinnerDateModel

.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class TimeZoneSpinners {

    private final String[] zones = {"Asia/Tokyo", "Asia/Hong_Kong",
        "Asia/Calcutta", "Europe/Paris", "Europe/London",
        "America/New_York", "America/Los_Angeles"
    };
    private final JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[zones.length];
    private final SimpleDateFormat[] formats = new SimpleDateFormat[zones.length];
    private JSpinner spinner;
    private JSpinner spinnerDate;
    private JSpinner spinnerMonth;
    private JSpinner spinnerYear;
    private SpinnerDateModel model;
    private SimpleDateFormat format;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public void makeUI() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = cal.getTime();
        model = new SpinnerDateModel();
        model.setValue(date);
        spinner = new JSpinner(model);
        spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                Date date = (Date) ((JSpinner) e.getSource()).getValue();
                for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                    labels[i].setText(formats[i].format(date));
                }
            }
        });
        format = ((JSpinner.DateEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getFormat();
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(zones[0]));
        format.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(zones.length, 2, 10, 10));
        for (int i = 0; i < zones.length; i++) {
            formats[i] = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            formats[i].setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(zones[i]));
            JLabel label = new JLabel(zones[i]);
            labels[i] = new JLabel(formats[i].format(date));
            panel.add(label);
            panel.add(labels[i]);
        }
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        frame.add(spinner, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TimeZoneSpinners().makeUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i already read it,and realy confuse about it..  
i update my code.. i think what i do its not a good way.. is there other good way? 
realy-really thankz for the help and the advice..

Comment: `and realy confuse about it accepted` accepted, in the tutorial is described three ways 1) SpinnerListModel about String value, use in the case that you want to display month names instead of numbers, 2) SpinnerNumberModel in the case that you want to use munbers for all three JSpinners (day, month and year), 3) best of all is to use SpinnerDateModel that returns Date instance, or 4) I'll update with some code about JSpinner and SpinnerDateModel, rest is up to you, there no reason for parsing integer, or munber instance from JSpinner, to use SpinnerNumberModel only

Comment: thankz.. i already learn your script (its take a long time for me to understand ~,~" ,but finally i got it) but i still confuse how to get the relations with my script.. (forgive my stupidness)...    

i need int month value to set my calendar.. then with my calendar i  set my jlabel[day] based on calendar(month).. i update my complete code of my date picker.. how to doing this without parsing simpledateformat to int from jspinner result?

Comment: JLabel.setText(JSpinner1.getValue + "/" + JSpinner2.getValue + "/" + JSpinner3.getValue) in the ChangeListener

Answer (score 2):

Put appropriate parameter types, i.e. :

```
  cal.set(Integer.parseInt(sdf_Year.format(Syear.getValue())), 
          Integer.parseInt(sdf_Month.format(Smonth.getValue())),
          1);
```